TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, list, tuple with headers
or status, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a OperationalError
all wrong:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\12\PycharmProjects\ survey_site\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1498, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\12\PycharmProjects\ survey_site\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1476, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\12\PycharmProjects\ survey_site\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\12\PycharmProjects\ survey_site\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 883, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\12\PycharmProjects\ survey_site\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 902, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\12\PycharmProjects\ survey_site\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1211, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, list, tuple with headers or status, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a OperationalError.

code of the page where the error occurs:
@app.route('/create_survey', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_survey():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        flash("To get started, please register.")
        return redirect(url_for('home'))

    form = CreateSurveyForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_survey = Poll(
            author=current_user.username,
            title=form.title.data,
            description=form.description.data,
            question=form.question.data,
            answer_one=form.answer_one.data,
            answer_two=form.answer_two.data,
            answer_tree=form.answer_tree.data,
            answer_four=form.answer_four.data,
            answer_five=form.answer_five.data,
        )
        try:
            session.add(new_survey)
            session.commit()
            flash('your survey has been saved', "success")
            return redirect(url_for("home"))
        except Exception as exc:
            return exc
        finally:
            session.close()
    return render_template('create_survey.html', form=form)

app/template/create_survey.html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Create Servey  {% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<div class="forms">
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</div>
{% endblock %}

the code stops working when i click the submit button
need more details but I don't have much time
if you need something else, write

return exc won't work.  Perhaps return str(exc) will display the error on your webpage.
